# Get innerHTML of a tag without ID (and qtip)

Tags: javascript, html, qtip

I need to have the qtip tooltip text be equal to the value of every tag using `class="tip"` (e.g. "some number here"). Preferably without using ids.

```
<a class="tip">some number here</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tip').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: "tooltip here"
        }
    })
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="tip">some number here</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tip').each(function() {
    var tipNumber = $(this).text();
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: tipNumber;
        }
    })
 })
</script>
```

Comment: so I was just missing the brackets after $(this).text .. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

To access properties of the element that triggered the QTip, one must structure the code in this way:

```
$("#container a").each(function() { 
    $(this).qtip({ // QTip code });
});
```

That way, one can use $(this) to access data such as innerHTML of the element that triggered the QTip.

here is a working code: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/2501/